# React Native response error 500

Tags: android, iphone, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0jkT.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0jkT.jpg)

```
  I am doing following step to start react application
```

- react-native init reactTutorialApp
- react-native run-android

by followed these steps and it is installing on Device successfully. but i am getting a following error.

**The development server return response error code:500**

**PFA**

Comment: In the body of the error message, about thirteen lines down, there are suggested approaches to solving the issue. Have you tried those?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run one command, the one to start the development server.
Try:

```
react-native init reactTutorialApp
```

*run the following command in the project root folder, but in another tab (this process need to be running when you're developing:*
`react-native start`

*And now you can run:* `react-native run-android`

Tell me if it solve your problem.